# Is this a simile and is this a metaphor?

Tags: metaphors, rhetorical-devices, simile

The sentence is: To live on this farm is to live in the sky and the grass as well as the house.

Is "as well as the house" a simile or is it just saying something similar to "including the house"?

And is the whole sentence a metaphor? Can a sentence be a metaphor, and have a simile within that sentence at the same time?

Comment: You don't get to shout at us. Stop editing in screaming help words: you’re being rude and demanding

Comment: A simile is like a metaphor.

Comment: @HotLicks A metaphor is a simile, metaphorically. :)

Comment: Sicilia, what do you understand the words "simile" and "metaphor" to mean? Which element(s) of the sentence do you think might be a simile or a metaphor, and why? You need to explain where your uncertainty resides.

Comment: @Chappo Someone already answered my question, but thanks anyway for still trying to help. ;)

Comment: @Lawrence - As Will Rogers might say, I never metaphor I didn't simile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think either applies.

Treating “as well as the house” to be a simile wrenches the natural sense of the sentence to make it say that the house lives (quite well) on the farm. The natural sense of “as well as” here is really just something along the lines of “and also”.

To treat the whole thing as a metaphor requires it to be a metaphor for *something*. That’s also not apparent here. It looks simply like figurative / poetic language about aspects of life on a farm.